# Prevent strace from abbreviating arguments?

Tags: linux, strace

I'm trying to use strace to find out what commands a program executes using `execve`. Some of the arguments in these commands are quite long, and strace is abbreviating the arguments to `execve` (I see "..." after about 30 characters), preventing me from getting any useful information. How can I get the full text of each argument?

I've read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace). The -v option prints the environment, which is useful, but the arguments are still truncated.

```
strace -f -e trace=execve -v -p 1234
```

I also tried passing verbose=all, but this just gives some extra information about SIGCHLD.

```
strace -f -e verbose=all trace=execve -v -p 1234
```

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You want the `-v -s strsize` option, which specifies the maximum length of a string to display (the default is 32).

Comment: This doesn't work for "nested" or array arguments, e.g. `ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TEMPO or TCGETA, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...})`

Comment: it was solved at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365928/show-complete-arguments-in-strace/34373478#34373478

Comment: As another user noted in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365928/show-complete-arguments-in-strace-even-in-curly-brackets/34373478#34373478)
"-v argument works as of 4.15 and seems to have been there since the creation time of the Git repo." So you don't have to alter the source of the package, -v should work just fine with nested objects.

Comment: `-v` alone did not work for in verson 5.5.   However, using `-s strsize` alone, without `-v` actually solves abbreviation problem for "nested" arguments.

Comment: `strace -s 1000 myBinary`

Comment: To be clear: in Ubuntu v20+, `strace -v -s 9999` does show the unabbreviated string/array in calls to `execve()` ... of course as well as more extensive detail for everything else.