# Which linux system call is used by ls command in linux to display the folder/file name?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls, ls

I wanted to know which system call is used in linux by the ls command to display the folder's (or file's name)? Especially the files/folders starting with "." (dot)

I executed the `strace ls -a` command to look at the system calls.There is a lot of `fstat` calls which occur for the all the other attributes (inode to permisisons).  Which one actually gives it's name?

```
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "-a"], [/* 37 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1762000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1c14025000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=109464, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 109464, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1c1400a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20T\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=121936, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2221680, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1c13be6000
mprotect(0x7f1c13c03000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1c13e02000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x7f1c13e02000
mmap(0x7f1c13e04000, 1648, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1c13e04000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31752, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128984, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1c139de000
mprotect(0x7f1c139e5000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1c13be4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f1c13be4000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\33\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31096, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1c14009000
mmap(NULL, 2126312, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1c137d6000
mprotect(0x7f1c137dd000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1c139dc000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f1c139dc000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\30\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1811128, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3925208, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1c13417000
mprotect(0x7f1c135cc000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1c137cb000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b4000) = 0x7f1c137cb000
mmap(0x7f1c137d1000, 17624, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1c137d1000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14768, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109704, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1c13213000
mprotect(0x7f1c13215000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1c13415000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f1c13415000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=135366, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1c14008000
mmap(NULL, 2212904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1c12ff6000
mprotect(0x7f1c1300e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1c1320d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7f1c1320d000
mmap(0x7f1c1320f000, 13352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1c1320f000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\17\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18552, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1c12df1000
mprotect(0x7f1c12df5000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1c12ff4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f1c12ff4000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1c14007000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1c14005000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f1c140057c0) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c137cb000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c12ff4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c1320d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c13415000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c139dc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c13be4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c13e02000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x618000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c14027000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f1c1400a000, 109464)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f1c14005a90)         = 4490
set_robust_list(0x7f1c14005aa0, 0x18)   = 0
futex(0x7fff2e09d99c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7f1c140057c0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f1c12ffc750, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f1c13005cb0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f1c12ffc7e0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f1c13005cb0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/selinux", {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=238304997, f_bfree=232078639, f_bavail=219973436, f_files=60530688, f_ffree=60120220, f_fsid={-1173666966, -474985328}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1762000
brk(0x1783000)                          = 0x1783000
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1c14024000
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 1024) = 328
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f1c14024000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7220736, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 7220736, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1c1270e000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=41, ws_col=144, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1c14024000
write(1, ".  ..\n", 6.  ..
)                  = 6
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f1c14024000, 4096)            = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Most of the system calls there are noise from loading shared libraries at startup.  The interesting things happen here:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)
```

The [`openat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/openat) system call is used to open the current directory (`"."`) relative to the current working directory (the `AT_FDCWD` flag).  The `O_DIRECTORY` flag indicates that it wants to open the directory and read the directory's contents.

The actual directory data is read using the [`getdents(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getdents) system call.  In this case, it called it twice, since until it returns 0, it's not sure if there's more data or not.  Finally, the file descriptor is closed after it's done.

If you were to write your own program, however, you wouldn't call these directly -- instead you'd use [`opendir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir), [`readdir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir), and [`closedir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/closedir) to read a directory.  They're portable (POSIX-compliant), and they insulate you from the details of the underlying system calls.  They're also easier to use, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

it is the [stat(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html) syscall which query the status of some file (perhaps a directory); if you have a file descriptor (after an `open(2)` syscall) you can use [fstat(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fstat.2.html)

To read a directory, you'll better use the `readdir(3)` function which calls the [getdents(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/gettdents.2.html) syscall.

Answer (score 0):

**More verbose `strace` dump**

[Prevent strace from abbreviating arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672743/prevent-strace-from-abbreviating-arguments) teaches us how:

```
strace -v -s 99999 ls
```

If we create some distinctly named test files on an empty directory:

```
touch aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
touch bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
touch cccccccccccccccccccc
```

and now search for `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` on the output we see the following two hits (`getdents64` manually indented by me):

```
getdents64(3, [
    {d_ino=8328002, d_off=1, d_reclen=24, d_type=DT_DIR, d_name="."},
    {d_ino=1536544, d_off=2, d_reclen=24, d_type=DT_DIR, d_name=".."},
    {d_ino=8329332, d_off=358524250, d_reclen=40, d_type=DT_REG, d_name="cccccccccccccccccccc"},
    {d_ino=8329330, d_off=496322106, d_reclen=40, d_type=DT_REG, d_name="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
    {d_ino=8329756, d_off=497914259, d_reclen=40, d_type=DT_REG, d_name="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"}
], 131072) = 168

write(1, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  cccccccccccccccccccc\n", 65aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  cccccccccccccccccccc
```

We know that he write of course writes it to stdout, so it seems very likely that `getdents64` is the one getting the names. Besides the three files we created, we also see that the special `.` and `..` are also always present at the syscall level. Cool stuff.

`man getdents64` then confirms our suspicion. That page notably has a minimal sample code that heps quench any doubts.

The first argument of `getdents64` was `3`, which is a common number for the first file opened by a program (since 0, 1 and 2 are taken by stdin, stdout and stderr by default).

By searching above the `getdents64` for the number `3` we see:

```
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_dev=makedev(0, 0x27), st_ino=8328002, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=131072, st_blocks=18, st_size=5, st_atime=1665092404 /* 2022-10-06T22:40:04.155914251+0100 */, st_atime_nsec=155914251, st_mtime=1665092401 /* 2022-10-06T22:40:01.415910918+0100 */, st_mtime_nsec=415910918, st_ctime=1665092401 /* 2022-10-06T22:40:01.415910918+0100 */, st_ctime_nsec=415910918}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
getdents64(3,
```

so we understand that:

- something else had `3` open, but then closed it
- `openat` returned our `3` with input argument `"."`, since we implicitly listed the current working directory with `ls`
- `newfstatat` was used to get some metadata from it
- `getdents64` then used that descriptor

**Static source code analysis**

Let's have some fun to hopefully confirm the stuff other answers said, i.e.:

- `getdents` is the base syscall, or more precisely, `getdents64` on an x86_64 system like mine
- `opendir` and `readdir` are convenience helpers

[GNU Coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) is the most popular desktop implementation of `ls`, and the one I have on my Ubuntu 22.04 computer right now. We can find this with:

```
apt-file search '/usr/bin/ls'
```

and we know that it is at version 8.32 according to `dpkg -l | grep coreutils`.

Here's the file that implements it on a GitHub mirror: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/v8.32/src/ls.c#L2972 slightly summarized:

```
DIR *dirp;
struct dirent *next;
dirp = opendir (name);
while (1) {
    next = readdir (dirp);
    total_blocks += gobble_file (next->d_name, type,
                                RELIABLE_D_INO (next),
                                false, name);
```

`man readdir` tells us that `next->d_name` is the basename of the entry.

`gobble_file` then goes on to keep a list of entries, which is then printed at the end. This presumably has to be done because `readdir` does not return a deterministic order, and `ls` wants to print an ordered file list.

The functions `opendir` and `readdir` are implemented in most desktop systems in the [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glibc), which on my Ubuntu 22.04 is at version 2.35 according to `dpkg -l | grep libc6`.

`readir` is implemented at: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.35/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/readdir.c#L42

```
struct dirent *
__readdir_unlocked (DIR *dirp) {
      bytes = __getdents (dirp->fd, dirp->data, maxread);
}
weak_alias (__readdir, readdir)
```

`__getdents` is likely implemented at https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.35/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getdents64.c

```
ssize_t
__getdents64 (int fd, void *buf, size_t nbytes)
{
  /* The system call takes an unsigned int argument, and some length
     checks in the kernel use an int type.  */
  if (nbytes > INT_MAX)
    nbytes = INT_MAX;
  return INLINE_SYSCALL_CALL (getdents64, fd, buf, nbytes);
}
libc_hidden_def (__getdents64)
weak_alias (__getdents64, getdents64)
```

`INLINE_SYSCALL_CALL` is defined at https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.35/sysdeps/unix/sysdep.h and likely (it is an infinitely deep sea of macros) ends up calling the x86_64 assembly syscall helper at https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.35/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S#L29 which places syscall arguments one by one on the correct registers.

```
ENTRY (syscall)
    movq %rdi, %rax     /* Syscall number -> rax.  */
    movq %rsi, %rdi     /* shift arg1 - arg5.  */
    movq %rdx, %rsi
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    movq %r8, %r10
    movq %r9, %r8
    movq 8(%rsp),%r9    /* arg6 is on the stack.  */
    syscall         /* Do the system call.  */
    cmpq $-4095, %rax   /* Check %rax for error.  */
    jae SYSCALL_ERROR_LABEL /* Jump to error handler if error.  */
    ret         /* Return to caller.  */
```

some more comments: [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-and-user-space-f/54957101#54957101)

And the syscall number itself appears to come from https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.35/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64/arch-syscall.h#L90

```
#define __NR_getdents64 217
```

Finally on the [Linux kernel syscall table](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421750/where-do-you-find-the-syscall-table-for-linux) at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.15/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl#L228 we can confirm that the syscall 217 is the one for `getdents64`:

```
217 common  getdents64      sys_getdents64
```

**Step debug `ls` with debug symbols**

On Ubuntu 22.04 as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/487222/how-to-install-debug-symbols-for-installed-packages

```
# Get debug symbols.
printf "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com %s main restricted universe multiverse\n" $(lsb_release -cs){,-updates,-security,-proposed} | \
 sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
sudo apt update
sudo apt install coreutils-dbgsym

# Get source.
apt source coreutils

# Alternative less precise way to get sources.
# git clone --depth 1 --branch v8.32 https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils

# Run ls pointing to the downloaded source.
gdb -ex 'set substitute-path . /home/ciro/git/coreutils/coreutils-8.32/' ls
```

Upon starting on `main`:

```
start
```

we are at `src/ls.c` as expected.

We try:

```
break readdir
continue
```

but only to notice that we don't have glibc sources!

```
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/readdir64.c: No such file or directory.
```

So we get them:

```
apt source libc6
```

and then on GDB:

```
set substitute-path .. /home/ciro/git/coreutils/glibc-2.35
```

We use `..` here to match the weird `../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/readdir64.c` with which symbols were compiled.

OK, so now we are at `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/readdir64.c`:

```
struct dirent64 *
__readdir64 (DIR *dirp)
```

And so on.